# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to run an existing Rails application (cloned from Github), but when I try to do db:migrate, I get the following error. I get the same error when I run db:purge, db:schema:load, etc...

This is the error:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation 
"users" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                      ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, 
a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, 
a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                 c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS 
comment
            FROM pg_attribute a
            LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND 
a.attnum = d.adnum
            LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
            LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND 
a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Which existing Rails application? Can you get help from their Github account? They're more likely to be able to help than Stack Overflow as it sounds like a project specific error.

Comment: The error indicates that the users table does not exist, which suggests that your database was created but not setup.

Comment: You might try loading the schema instead of running the migrations.

Comment: did you try loading the schema directly using `rails db:schema:load` instead of running the migration?

Answer (score 2):

When cloning a Rails project and setting up the database, you don't want to run the migrations. Migrations are intended for incremental database updates, and it's quite likely that they get old and don't run anymore. You want to run `rake db:schema:load`, which directly loads the `db/schema.rb` file into the database.

If you want a shortcut to running the seeds as well, you can use `rake db:setup` which creates the database (`db:create`), loads the schema (`db:schema:load`), then runs the seeds (`db:seed`). You can also do `rake db:reset` which does the same thing but drops the database first.

For more info see the Rails Guides on this topic: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark

> There is no need (and it is error prone) to deploy a new instance of an app by replaying the entire migration history. It is much simpler and faster to just load into the database a description of the current schema.